# Outlook profile during staged migration

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office-365, exchange-migration

I'm in the final stages of testing a staged migration from Exchange 2007 to Online Exchange - I've synced and migrated a test user, and have verified that the user is now a MEU.

However, in Outlook on this test users computer it appears that I have to create a new profile at this point..

(If I create a new profile for the user, it works great, and the relay between exchange on-prem and 365 is working as expected)

BUT, do I need to create another new profile again once I change the MX Records to direct straight to 365? So that I have now created 2 new profiles for my users? I thought the point of staged migration was that the user continues to use their profile seamlessly, and it's only once the MX records are changed, that the user needs the new profile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you getting the "use temporary mailbox" message?  That's usually the case when the mailbox on the server and the OST file don't match. In this case you can access mailbox still - but the message won't go away until you re-build a new profile.

If all you see is an empty mailbox - that is most likely because you have not converted your users from mailbox enabled to mail enabled. As long as Exchange thinks it hosts your mailbox it will serve it to you. Once it's not looking for a mailbox locally it will now to reference the external address / targetaddress and AutoDiscover will redirect you to Office 365.  You will probably still have to rebuild the profile though to avoid nagging pop ups from the first paragraph.

Comment: Hey @jesus yes getting the "use temporary mailbox" message - so this message can be ignored, and the mail will continue as per normal? (unfortunately I didn't test this at the time, just created a new profile, but will create another test user in the meantime to find out..)

Comment: You can - but it will pop up every time Outlook starts.  The only fix is to create a new profile.